# Python CSV delete empty rows

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

Im having a hard time trying to delete empty(blank) rows from a csv file using python 3.4.3. Each time I run my script the output remains the same as the original.

```
  import csv
  ...


 with open('demo004.csv') as input, open('demo005.csv', 'w') as output:
      writer = csv.writer(output)
      for row in csv.reader(input):
          if any(field.strip() for field in row):
             writer.writerow(row)
      input.close()
      output.close()
```

My CSV file is in the format.

```
AA,AB,AC

BA,BB,BC

CA,CB,CB
```

Whereas I would like to obtain

```
AA,AB,AC
BA,BB,BC
CA,CB,CB
```

Comment: What is the delimiter in your original files? I'm guessing commas since you do not specify? If you could link some of the data in `demo004.csv` or `demo005.csv` that would be helpful

Comment: Please include a complete example in your posting, particularly a short data set for input, the output, and the desired output.  The file names shown won't let helpers duplicate the problem.

Comment: Is that the real code? Closing the input/output at that indentation level (which is unnecessary anyway giving the use of `with` statement) would be causing exceptions

Comment: Please provide enough code and sample data to replicate the problem.

Comment: I  using a "," as delimiter. I used the with statement because of the version of python according to what I read,

Comment: That gives me an invalid syntax  at "as".

Comment: Here is a screen shot http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=fvw7d4&s=8#.Vdj_fZdmo9s

Comment: @MichalK: your screenshot shows both that you removed the `with`, and it looks like you removed the colon you need at the end of the line. Start with your original code (which works for me) and simply add `newline=''` inside both opens.

Comment: That worked, kindly explain how the newline came into play. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

When you are trying to open the file which you want to write to, open it with an additional parameter, newline=''

```
import csv
  ...


 with open('demo004.csv') as input, open('demo005.csv', 'w', newline='') as output:
     writer = csv.writer(output)
     for row in csv.reader(input):
         if any(field.strip() for field in row):
             writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Please do not post links to [duplicate answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/211726/206345). Instead, consider other actions that could help future users find the answer they need, as described in the linked post.

Comment: Thank you for updating me. Have rectified !

Comment: I think you need to remove `newline = ''`

Comment: newline = ' ' has been added specifically for python 3.x. If you are using Python 2.x, you don't need the newline=' '

Answer (score 1):

If you're only interested in removing blank lines (ie, ones that are empty or perhaps contain only whitespace), then you don't need to worry about the fact that the other lines are CSV. That means you can just do:

```
with open('demo004.csv') as input, open('demo005.csv', 'w') as output:
    non_blank = (line for line in input if line.strip())
    output.writelines(non_blank)
```